# can the merchants disable the shopee's Buyer Info masking functionality

Tags: python, shopee

I am consuming the Shopee API "get_order_detail" and Im getting masked data in the shipping section of the response as shown below

```
{'name': '****', 'phone': '****', 'town': '****', 'district': '****', 'city': '****', 
'state': '****', 'region': '****', 'zipcode': '****', 'full_address': '****'}.
```

May I know if merchants have the ability or other alternatives to unmask this data as we use this shipping_adderess data for creating an order.

Comment: I suggest you look at documentation for the shopee api